# MIPS Assembly : Printing number as a 56 bytes char

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I was looking to learn a bit more about assembly and was looking for some help in a project i found.

The program should take a random number and print it out as a 56 bytes char (8 bytes * 7 lines per char).

Something similar to this:
[image: 56 Bytes Print]

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think QTSPIM has cursor-position system calls, so printing will have to go horizontally across one line of every digit, then on to the next line of every digit.

You probably want a bitmap lookup table per line per glyph.  Or even a string if you want to use a lot of space and avoid writing code to convert a bitmap to a series of spaces and `#` characters

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response.
You are right, QTSPIM has no cursor-position system calls, and therefore i'd have to print every line of every digit.

I was thinking of using a string to print out the result, but i can't honestly figure out how.

Comment: @HugoPinto: You could copy chunks into one big string, or you could use string-print system calls on each vertical line of each digit separately, from tables indexed by the digit and the current vertical position.

Comment: Would you care to explain with an example?